# String is not convertible to NSMutableString

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsmutablestring

It works fine to cast a Swift `String` as an `NSString`.

```
let string = "some text"
let nsString = string as NSString
```

But when I do

```
let string = "some text"
let nsMutableString = string as NSMutableString
```

I get the error

> 'String' is not convertible to 'NSMutableString'

How to I convert it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot cast a `String` as an `NSMutableString`, but you can use an `NSMutableString` initializer.

```
let string = "some text"
let nsMutableString = NSMutableString(string: string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code it shows error

```
   'NSString' is not a subtype of 'NSMutableString'
```

If you want to convert string to NSMutableString in swift by simply constructing it with NSMutableString(string: ...)

```
   let string = "some text"
   let nsMutableString = NSMutableString(string: string)
```

Above code works fine.